# Как при вёрстке письма для outlook сделать масштаб 101%?

Tags: html, css, outlook

Есть ли такая настройка , подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать CSS-свойство zoom, которое нужно задать родительскому элементу.

```
zoom: 101%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Для применения масштаба 101% письма для Outlook можно использовать следующий код:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
    body, table, td {
        font-size: 10.0pt !important;
        line-height: 11.0pt !important;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```